# Correlation between 2 linear combinations of the same variables / variables in the linear span of 2 vectors

Tags: correlation

I have 2 ***normally distributed*** variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

$Y_1 = aX_1 + bX_2$

$Y_2 = cX_1 + dX_2$

There is no $\epsilon$.

ie.

$Y_1 = aX_1 + bX_2 + (\epsilon=0)$

$Y_2 = cX_1 + dX_2 + (\epsilon=0)$

I wish to know if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated.

I may use the formula to find the covariance of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$:

$cov(Y_1,Y_2)=$

$ cov(aX_1 + bX_2,cX_1 + dX_2)$ = ac $Var(X_1)$ +ad $cov(X_1,X_2)$ +bc $cov(X_1,X_2)$ + bd $Var(X_2)$

There does seem ***some*** covariance.

Now I am unable to see if Y_1 and Y_2 are correlated ***intuitively***.

Example 1: Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.
Then the above covariance will only have the variance terms on the RHS (since the covariance terms will be equal to zero) .

Example 2: Suppose ***further*** that ac = -bd and $Var(X_1)$ = $Var(X_2)$, then the RHS = 0.

Can I make a comment on the correlation or covariance of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ which is ***precise***?

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ belong to the linear span of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Does that shed light on the correlation between them ? May I know how close to 1 will the correlation between them can be?

Another example for intuition: $X_1$ and $X_2$ may be equal to a common variable $X_3$ + white noise.
So when I compute $Y_1$ = $1 X_1$ + $1 X_2$ and $Y_2$  = $1 X_1 - 1 X_2$ the $X_3$ cancels out and I am left with only the noise in the $Y_2$.

Comment: You should express this mapping as a matrix vector product: $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ contains the coefficients $a,b,c,d$. Then, we can use the formula $\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{A}\mathbb{V}[\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{A}^\top$. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated iff the top right/bottom left elements of this matrix are nonzero. If $X_1$ is indep of $X_2$ with same variance,  this is true iff $[a,b]^\top [c,d]=0$. PS: the linear span of $X_1,X_2$ is not a concept that makes sense since these are scalars. PPS: these conclusions hold w/o normality assumptions.

Comment: @JohnMadden That should be an answer! not a comment.

Comment: @JohnMadden In $y=Ax$, I can assume that $x$ is a column of 2 vectors $X_1$  and $X_2$ and that $y$ is a column of 2 vectors $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are 2 arbitrary but fixed vectors in the linear span of $X_1$ and $X_2$, no?

Comment: @user2338823 When you say "a column of two vectors $X_1$ and $X_2$", it sounds like in your notation $X_1$ and $X_2$ are vectors, which isn't obvious from the question: it sounds like from the question like these are (scalar) gaussian variables. If you meant that you stack the scalars $X_1$ and $X_2$ to form the vector $\mathbf{x}$, we're still not there: for $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ to be in the span of $\mathbf{x}$ would mean that $\mathbf{y} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$ for some constant $\lambda$, or in other words, that $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: While @JonMaddens matrix approach is great, i have to disagree with him about one thing: The set of real valued random variables is closed under both addition ($X +Y$) and scalar multiplication ($rX, r\in \mathbb R$), making it a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and so it is perfectly valid to speak about the span of such random variables.

Comment: In fact if we restrict our selves to $L^2$, i.e. random variables $X$ such that $E[X] < \infty$, then we can define an inner, sometimes called dot or scalar, product $<X,Y> = E[XY]$(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Random_variables). Now for mean centered variables  that's the covariance and since $||X|| =\sqrt{<X,X>}$ always defines a valid norm, the standard deviation is the corresponding norm, i.e. length of the vectors.

Comment: Further since in euclidean geometry $<\vec x,\vec y> = \cos(\angle(\vec x,\vec y)) \cdot||\vec x||\cdot ||\vec y||$, we can understand correlation $\frac{<X,Y>}{||X||\cdot ||Y||}$ as the cosine of an abstract angle $\angle(X,Y)$, which is why we call being uncorrelated orthogonal. Sorry for the long comments, I just always wanted to point that out.

Comment: @LukasLohse I know it can be tempting to share things that we've learned and find exciting, but could you please clarify how any of this helps resolve OP's confusion? In mathematical pedagogy, we have to choose between rigor and clarity, and in my view it just does not make sense to bring functional analytic notions into this conversation. If you're commenting because you're worried that I might not be aware of hilbert spaces, then allow this comment to set those worries to rest.

Comment: @LukasLohse PS: if you think the linear perspective of random variables is cool (which it totally is!), you should check out the manifold perspective next, which goes under the name *information geometry*.

Comment: @John Madden, Sorry for the long time between responses. I was very busy and maybe a tiny bit embarrassed, but i still wanted to say thank you for recommending information geometry. It's exactly the kind of thing i need to distract me from how horribly applied my job can be :)